# Append soap raw request/response to a stringbuilder or to a log file

Tags: java, spring, apache, web-services

I wrote a sample soap service project using apache cxf, and I used log4j with in this app for logging. I can log the soap raw request and response to server console , but I couldn't log this to a log file or to a stingBuilder . And my 
cxf-beans.xml like this

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="http://source.sprint.com/"
        id="accountinfoservice" implementor="com.sprint.source.AccountInfoServiceImpl"
        wsdlLocation="wsdl/accountinfoserviceimpl.wsdl" endpointName="tns:AccountInfoServiceImplPort"
        serviceName="tns:AccountInfoServiceImplService" address="/AccountInfoServiceImplPort">
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>


</beans>**
```

Client class

```
AccountInfoServiceImplService service= new AccountInfoServiceImplService();
    com.sprint.stubs.AccountInfoService op=service.getAccountInfoServiceImplPort();
    //System.out.println(op.getAccountInfo("123").getSuspendInd());

    logger.info("hello");

        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(op);
        client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
        logger.info("response  "+client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor()));
        logger.info("request   "+client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor()));
        System.out.println(op.getAccountInfo("123").getFirstName());
```

logger.info("request   "+client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor())); this peace of code logged as true in logging file. If I use this configuration file and with client java class I'm able log raw request and response to console but I couldn't make to a log file, Then I search for ..
I changed configuration file like this

```
    <bean id="abstractLoggingInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractLoggingInterceptor" abstract="true" />
    <bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor" />
    <bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" parent="abstractLoggingInterceptor" />

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus>
    <jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="http://source.sprint.com/"
        id="accountinfoservice" implementor="com.sprint.source.AccountInfoServiceImpl"
        wsdlLocation="wsdl/accountinfoserviceimpl.wsdl" endpointName="tns:AccountInfoServiceImplPort"
        serviceName="tns:AccountInfoServiceImplService" address="/AccountInfoServiceImplPort">
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

After changing configuration file , I got `"org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)"`

I search for this solution over net, but I couldn't make it? can any one help me out of this

Answer (score 0):

Use org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12 instead log4j:log4j in dependecies, check logger level in log4j.xml:

```
<logger name="org.apache.cxf">
    <level value="info"/>
</logger>
```